# Show() window wait for a button to be pressed and mainWindow active (WPF)

Tags: wpf, dialog

`InteractiveWindow` contain YES and NO button. The current solution is displaying the `InteractiveWindow` on `MainWIndow` without having access to `MainWindow`. `InteractiveWindow` is also a `Window` (not a `UserControl`). How is possible to transform my dialog window in order to have my `InteractiveWindow` on top of my `MainWindow` and be able to access `MainWindow` until one of the two buttons are pressed?

```cs
internal async Task<bool> Test()
{
      // some code

        var test= new InteractiveWindow();
        test.Owner = this;
        test.ShowDialog();

        // some other code
        return true;
}
```

Old code for one of the button:

```cs
private void YES_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    GetWindow(this).DialogResult = true;
    this.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```cs
test.Show()
```

instead of `test.ShowDialog()`, because `ShowDialog()` is blocking. Even though your method is `async`, it executes synchronously until it needs to `await` an incomplete `Task`, so your `Test` method is blocking because there is no such `await` statement. I suggest you remove this `async` modifier if you don't use it.